# Setting Binding Expression in WPF DataGrid Column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, expression

As we can add expression in Data Column of Data Table, is it possible to create Column like `DataGridTextColumn` and set `Binding Expression?`
If Yes then How?

As I am creating My Own `DataGridComputedColumn` For `WPF DataGrid`, which allows to set expression for that column so that at run time when DataSource is attached it automatically evaluates this Computed Column at run time.

For Example I have table EMP With 2 Columns FirstName and LastName. This will be `DataGridTextColumn` in `WPF DataGrid`. Now the third column will be My own Custom `DataGridComputedColumn` Which has property like expression in which i can set expression as `FirstName +' ' + LastName` which on run time evaluates and generate third column.

Thanks
Visshal

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an expression in your binding property. However you can write it with an `IValueConverter`:

```
public class FirstAndLastnameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var emp = value as Employee;
        return  string.Format("{0} {1}", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <me:FirstAndLastnameConverter x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```